# Crear varios archivos PDF mediante Ciclo (Bucle) en PHP

Tags: php

estoy realizando un pequeño código para crear varios archivos, pero al ejecutarlo, únicamente se crea un archivo, el ejemplo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class automate_pdf extends FPDF{    
    function generate($name){
        if(isset($name)){
            $nombrePDF = 'PDF'. $name.'.pdf';
            $pdf = new FPDF();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf ->Image('img/wpmu-icon.png');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
            $pdf->Cell(40,10,'¡Hola, Mundo!' . $name);
            $pdf->Output( $nombrePDF, "D");
            //ob_end_clean();
            //$pdf -> Output();
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Mando a llamar la funcion con el siguiente código:

```
<?php
    include 'crearpdf.php';
    $i =0;
    while($i=3):
        //echo $i .'<BR>';
        $arcpdf = new automate_pdf();
        //$i . "<BR>";
        //echo $nombre = $i; 
        $arcpdf->generate($i);
        $i++;
    endwhile;
?>
```

Es un ejemplo muy básico de lo que deseo realizar, ojala puedan orientarme en esto, Muchas gracias por su atención.

Comment: Dentro del while no estas haciendo una comparación, sino una asignación. Cambia `$i=3` por `$i <= 3` y supongo que te saldrá mejor.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, ya intente realizar de esa manera; sin embargo, solo crea un archivo.

Comment: Acabo de darte una respuesta. Si la ves correcta deberias aceptarla para que la pregunta no quede pendiente para siempre. Léete este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para aprender a aceptar respuestas correctas, y de paso haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio y ver porque es importante la aceptación de respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He reproducido tu pregunta en mi PC y he visto lo siguiente:

1. Como ya habia dicho en los comentarios de tu pregunta, estas poniendo mal esto:

```
while($i=3):
```

que tiene que ser esto:

```
while($i <= 3):
```

porque sino entras en un bucle infinito fácilmente.

2. En el archivo **crearpdf.php** tienes puesta esta línea:

```
$pdf->Output( $nombrePDF, "D");
```

donde el parámetro **D** implica descargar el archivo que estás creando, en lugar de crearlo en disco.

***Y aquí es donde está el problema que tienes***, pues crees que solo lo hace una vez, cuando lo que ocurre es que durante el segundo ciclo tu programa se corta por este error:

```
PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

que viene causado porque la opción **D**, dentro del archivo `fpdf.php`, lo que intenta es esto:

```
case 'D':
    // Download file
    $this->_checkoutput();
    header('Content-Type: application/x-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; '.$this->_httpencode('filename',$name,$isUTF8));
    header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    echo $this->buffer;
    break;
```

Es decir, establece unos `header` para la cabecera HTTP, que finalmente terminan cuando se envia el archivo mediante el `echo $this->buffer`.

Durante el primer ciclo del bucle eso no es problema, pero al llegar al segundo no puede volver a establecer los **header** porque ya se ha establecido una salida previa con el `echo $this->buffer` del primero.

Dicho de otro modo, cuando se envian **header** y luego se envia algo más, no se pueden reenviar **header** de nuevo.

Tal como dice la [documentación de header()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php):

> Recuerde que header() debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por
> pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde
> PHP.

Por lo tanto, durante el segundo ciclo ya estamos rompiendo esa norma, pues ya hemos enviado un archivo previamente.

Segun esto creo que lo que pretendías era una descarga múltiple de archivos PDF con una sola invocación a tu código, lo cual no es posible tal como acabo de explicar.

Creo que lo que deberias hacer es modificar esa línea por esta:

```
$pdf->Output( $nombrePDF, "F");
```

pues el parámetro **F** te creará los archivos en el servidor sin problemas, y luego los puedes descargar mediante enlaces directos si sabes los nombres, o bien, cuando termine de crearlos, muestras sus url en la salida para su descarga mediante enlaces directos.

Esto es lo que hace el parámetro **F**:

```
case 'F':
    // Save to local file
    if(!file_put_contents($name,$this->buffer))
            $this->Error('Unable to create output file: '.$name);
    break;
```

O bien, una vez creados en disco, los puedes comprimir en un solo archivo, borrarlos, y entonces enviar el archivo comprimido para su descarga, pero eso ya queda fuera del ámbito de esta respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tomaré en concideración lo que me acabas de explicar, y ya vere que ocurre, gracias